# How to enter text in Editor?

Tags: javascript

I'm having this weird issue and can't seem to figure it out. Basically, I only want to allow the user to enter up to **40** characters in Editor, and if user enters more than **40** characters simply stop them. That part works great. However, after entering 41 characters CK Editor seems to freeze and I can't **delete/add** more characters at all. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt) { 
  evt.editor.on('key', function(event){
    if(evt.editor.getData().length > 40){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: May be this will help you http://jsfiddle.net/H2szq/635/

Comment: @TanDuong Why not post an answer using SO's code editor?

Comment: @LeeTaylor: I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something you are looking for

```
CKEDITOR.instances.foo.on('key',function(event){
        var deleteKey = 46;
        var backspaceKey = 8;
        var keyCode = event.data.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === deleteKey || keyCode === backspaceKey)
            return true;
        else
        {
            var textLimit = 40;
            var str = CKEDITOR.instances.foo.getData();
            if (str.length >= textLimit)
                return false;
        }
    });
```

You need to allow delete keycode

http://jsfiddle.net/H2szq/635/

Comment: @HenryDev: I answered this. You can check